# Why does a gold sequence have $2^m + 1$ symbols while a single m-sequence has only $2^m - 1$

Tags: frequency-spectrum

As explained in [here](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4450/en/):

> Gold sequences help generate more sequences out of a pair of
>   m-sequences giving now many more different sequences to have multiple
>   users. Gold sequences are based on preferred pairs m-sequences.
>
> For example, take the polynomials $x^5+x^2+1$ and
>   $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$:

[image]

> **By combining two of these sequences, we can obtain up to 31 plus the two m-sequences themselves, generate 33 sequences.**

I do understand why there are 31 ($2^5 - 1$) sequence length for a single m-sequence, but I am not sure why there are $2^5 + 1$ for the gold sequence.

Comment: Should be $2^5+1$ instead of $2^5+2$. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the preferred pair, each of length $2^m-1$. The other sequences are generated by modulo-2 addition of one of these sequences with cyclical shifts of the other sequence. There are $2^m-1$ possible shifts, so you get $2^m-1$ new sequences from the modulo-2 additions (one for each possible shift). And you still have the two original sequences of the preferred pair giving a total of $2^m-1+2=2^m+1$ sequences.

Comment: what is the preferred pair definition?

Comment: @0x90: A preferred pair results in better cross-correlation (and auto-correlation) properties of the generated Gold code than other pairs of sequences. Gold found a method to select such a preferred pair.